# How to show that $I_tdX_t + I_tP_tX_t dt = d(I_tX_t)$ using Ito's Lemma?

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

$dX_t +P_tX_tdt = dB_t$ and the integrating factor is $I_t = e^{\int{P_t dt}}$

Comment: $P_t $ is a deterministic function or a stochastic process?

Comment: $P_t$ is deterministic while $X_t$ is stochastic.

Answer (score 1):

$$d(u.v)=u.dv+v.du$$
put $I_t = e^{\int{P_t dt}}$
$$d(I_tX_t)=X_tdI_t+I_tdX_t\\=X_t d(e^{\int{P_t dt}})+I_tdX_t\\
=X_t (e^{\int{P_t dt}})d(\int{P_t dt})+I_tdX_t\\
=X_t (e^{\int{P_t dt}})P_t dt+I_tdX_t\\=
X_t I_t P_t dt+I_tdX_t$$ hence 
by multiplying integral factor 
  we have complete differential in Left hand side
$$dX_t+P_t X_t dt=dB_t \ to \\d(I_tX_t)=I_t dB_t$$ apply integral both sides
$$\int d(I_sX_s)=\int I_s dB_s \to \\I_tX_t-I_0X_0=\int I_s dB_s\\I_tX_t=I_0X_0+\int I_s dB_s \to  \\
X_t=I_t^{-1}I_0X_0+I_t^{-1}\int I_s dB_s $$

Comment: $d[X_t ,I_t]$ ? .   $P_t$ is  a deterministic function?

Comment: Let $dX_t+\underbrace{\sigma \sqrt{{{X}_{t}}}}_{{{P}_{t}}}\,  X_t dt=dB_t $

Comment: I assume that ,$P_t$ is deterministic .

Comment: Anyway.... (+1)